# Using PHP script to replace a field in HTML form

Tags: php

I need to use PHP script to replace the 7th character of a HTML form input Field.

Eg.

A234591Q

To become

A23459IQ

Replacing  number1 with I letter.

The problem is that I don’t have acess to php script file, so I need to do it in HTML page as customer types data, or at submit time.

Moises

Comment: Use JavaScript. Just Google string replace JavaScript

Comment: So you want to change something with PHP, but you don't have access to PHP?

Comment: Yes, I cannot treat  $myvariable or whatever name it has inside php script, so I have to treat the HTML file which will be passed to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the **JQuery** library linked on your page, then you can try the following.

First you should give your input an `ID` e.g `<input type="text" id="useranswer">`
Then set the `onsubmit` property of your HTML form to:

```
<form action="" onSubmit="replaceAt(7,$('#useranswer').val())">
```

Then define the replaceAt Function.

```
function replaceAt(index,word){
    newWord=word.substr(0,index) + 'l' + word.substr(index+1);
    $('#useranser').val(newWord);
}
```

I have just given the answer for your question as it is not clear how you plan to implement it without access to the source

Comment: I already have:

<form method="post" action="MYSCRIPT://DoRegister">

Can form "<form action="".." be placed after it or in what line of form ?

Inside the funcion is (0,index) + "1" or (0,index) + 'I' ?

Comment: "Given the answer I have just given for your question it is not clear how you plan to implement it without access to the source"

Because the field value is passed to the variable by post method form method="post" action="MYSCRIPT://DoRegister

So I think it is enough the treat the field.

Comment: You are to replace the form action in the example with your own which in this case is action="MYSCRIPT://DoRegister" so you will have <form action="MYSCRIPT://DoRegister" method="Post" onsubmit="replaceAt(7,$('#useranswer').val())" >